# What Windows 10 edition corresponds to Windows 7 Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, upgrade

I'm currently running a machine of my own making (about one year old), with Windows 7 Ultimate x64 as the operating system.

If I decide to upgrade to Windows 10 using the free upgrade offer from Microsoft, what edition of Windows 10 would I get?

Based on my web searches (using Google Search) it appears as if I would get Windows 10 Pro, but I'm not sure. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Whatever edition it is, you should upgrade to it. There is no good reason not to. The upgrade is not permanent. No one will hold you a prisoner of Windows 10. You can always go back to your old Windows version. Your original license is not invalidated when you upgrade. You can use it again, and if it's the retail license then you can even reuse it on other machines. It's just that when you upgrade to Windows 10 for free, you acquire one new license that is valid for that particular PC.

Comment: So you can upgrade to Windows 10 now, then downgrade to Windows 7, and when you have changed your mind about Windows 10 you can come back to it without having to pay for the upgrade or a full license. So be it Windows 10 Home or Pro, I suggest you upgrade to it in any case. Then go back to Windows 7 if you don't like it, yet be assured that a free copy of Windows 10 will be waiting for you should you change your mind, perhaps when Windows 10 has matured more over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the upgrade chart, you will get W10 Pro

[image]

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/upgrade-to-windows-10-faq)

Comment: Thanks. I was for this site but my Google Fu failed

Comment: Try google karate next time ;-)

Comment: I will. Chop chop

Comment: Those users coming from Windows 7 Professional are in for a bargain, because Windows 10 Pro is more feature packed than the similarly named Windows 7 Professional. The Windows 10 Pro is the new Ultimate.

Comment: Call me old fashioned if you like, but nothing says more than a good old ASCII styled table! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You think good. You will get `Pro` version.

Comment: You gave the answer but don't know why someone down voted.

Comment: A simple question deserves a simple answer like that. The only thing Misaz has done differently from the accepted answer is that he neglected to add a source that backs up his claim (and a big ugly screenshot of the web page text for posterity).

Comment: @sammyg a picture is a worth ~ 2^10 words, right? ;-)

Comment: @JCM Not necessarily you know. That depends on the picture! ;-) The problem with taking pictures of text is that you can't index and make the text searchable. Not unless you run the picture through some OCR algorithm, and even then, it's rarely interpreted 100% accurately. Because that's what it is, it's a guess work! Exotic fonts, foreign language symbols, mix of languages in the text, and various formatting elements is among those things that stand in the way of accurate OCR interpretation.

Comment: @JCM So it's for this reason that I actually prefer to copy and paste text directly off of a web page, instead of taking pictures of it. But one thing that pictures are very good at is describing form and layout. So I very much welcome screenshots of program windows, dialog boxes, menus, etc. Where the user is supposed to visually navigate and click on some item. But yeah... that's the way I see it. I generally welcome pictures and screenshots, and I'm a very visual person. But pictures of text... nah... I rather copy and paste the text. :-)

Comment: @JCM That screenshot is worth just 2^7 words + 1. Trust me, I counted them! That's roughly 1/8 of the claimed 2^10. ;-)

Comment: @JCM I just made an ASCII table of that picture. It's definitely better formatted than what Microsoft has to offer, and it's more readable than a picture ever could be.

Comment: "You think good" is broken English; that by itself; warrants a downvote.  I even question if the second sentence is even a sentence....Answers with broken English, non-sourced answers, are legitimacy reasons not to find an answer helpful.  "Windows 7 Ultimate installations are upgraded to Windows 10 Professional" is a single sentence; Just saying....